# Graphite edit dashboard

Tags: graphite, collectd

I installed collectd, graphite(0.9.10), carbon and whisper on a debian box. Graphite displays the captured data correctly and I can build a dashboard with it.

The documentation(http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dashboard.html) also mention that it's possible to edit and export data via JSON, but for any reason that doesn't work. If I go to a dashboard and click on the dashboard menu, then I can't see "Edit Dashboard".

Do you have any idea how to get "Edit Dashboard" in the dashboard working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a difference between the [documentation for the version you have installed](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/dashboard.html) and the [documentation you are reading](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dashboard.html).

According to the [downloads page](https://launchpad.net/graphite/+download), 0.9.10 was released on the 31st of May, 2012.
According to the [commit history](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/commit/90908e6d7fd3ffeee71ae1118f651e281aa3a58b), in-place dashboard editing was added on the 3rd of January, 2013.

It looks like a [0.9.11 release](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/tree/0.9.11-pre1) [is due soon](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/issues/106).

If you *need* the bleeding-edge features right now, you will have to [get the code fresh from Github](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web).

Beware if you go this route, you will get the bleeding-edge bugs along with the bleeding-edge features.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to export/import in 0.9.10. The urls are:
/dashboard/load/
to get dashboard description as json
and
/dashboard/save/
to save/update. In this case it is a POST request with data sent as - state=url_encoded_json

I put my url encoded data into a test_dash.txt file that contained a single like as
state=url_encoded_json
format and then used curl:
curl -d @test_dash.txt http:///dashboard/save/test_dash

NOTE: the data retrieved from /dashboard/load includes {"state": } at the top level that needs to be removed before being sent to /dashboard/save